# difference between "universal vaccination" and "vaccine roll-out"

Tags: phrase-meaning

What's the difference between "universal vaccination" and "vaccine roll-out"?
Since the start of this pandemic I've heard both terms, but have never quite been able to tell the difference. Dictionaries don't explain the difference. Wiki doesn't have a page on "vaccine roll-out", only on "vaccine", but the difference between these two terms is not explained there.

Comment: Did you search for meanings of "universal" and of "roll-out"?

Comment: @Davo - Of course, I did.

Comment: We don't know that if you don't put it in the quesiton.

Comment: @Davo: There is this phrase in my question: "Dictionaries don't explain the difference"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"universal vaccination" refers to vaccination accessible to all people (*universal* = involving everyone). Similar terms include

- [universal health care](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universal_health_care) (a system in which all residents of a particular country or region are assured access to health care),
- [universal design](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universal_design) (the design of buildings, products or environments to make them accessible to all people),
- [universal service](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universal_service) (the practice of providing a baseline level of services to every resident of a country).

"vaccine roll-out" describes an occasion when a new vaccine enters the marker, gradually becomes available to more people. Similarly, you can roll out a new product/technology/software update.